# Changing to display object position in corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk, moai

I am new to programming this question might sound very simple.
I have created a object as a module called box

```
box = {}
m={}
m.random = math.random

function box:new(x,y)
     box.on=false
     local box = display.newRect(0,0,100,100)
     box:setFillColor(m.random(120,200),m.random(120,200),m.random(120,200))
     box.x = x
     box.y = y
     box.type = "box"


     return box
end


return box
```

in my main.lua I want to create as many boxes and ,like an adventure game how can I switch two of the boxes position,example I click on one of them,then it is selected,and simply I click on the other one and they change position with each other.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Corona, but the general logic for what you're doing is this:

- Add an event handler which allows you to detect when a box is clicked.
- Add some way of tracking the selected box.
- When a box is clicked:

  - if no box is yet selected, select the current box
  - if another box was previously selected, swap with the current box
  - if the already-selected box was clicked, ignore (or toggle off selected)

---

General idea (not sure if this is valid Corona event handling, but should get you close):

```
box = {}
m={}
m.random = math.random

-- track the currently selected box
local selected = nil

function box:new(x,y)
     box.on=false
     local box = display.newRect(0,0,100,100)
     box:setFillColor(m.random(120,200),m.random(120,200),m.random(120,200))
     box.x = x
     box.y = y
     box.type = "box"
     function box:touch(event)
         if not selected then
             -- nothing is selected yet; select this box
             selected = self
             -- TODO: change this box in some way to visually indicate that it's selected
         elseif selected == self then
             -- we were clicked on a second time; we should probably clear the selection
             selected = nil
             -- TODO: remove visual indication of selection
         else
             -- swap positions with the previous selected box, then clear the selection
             self.x, self.y, selected.x, selected.y 
                 = selected.x, selected.y, self.x, self.y
             selected = nil
         end
     end
     return box
end
```

Comment: Thanks,one question ,why you put the selected = nil  outside the function?

Comment: Purely for documentation purposes, to show that we're creating a global of that name, rather than having it created sneakily inside of `box:touch`. Better would be to make it local, to limit its scope (I'll make that change now). Even better would be for it to be a property of the box class itself (not box *instances*). However, you named your box *class* and your box *instances* the same thing, so I would have had to make more changes to your code to implement that approach and I was trying to keep changes to a minimum.

Comment: Thanks,a lot.You know how you have used "local selected = nil" as a flag,I have tried "box.on = false" as a flag and box property,instead of "local selected =nil",and I have bit of difficulty with it.Is there any reason to that?

Comment: Yes, because the flag has to be shared by all box instances. You're giving each box it's own flag. You *could* put the flag in the box *class* (where you have the `new` method), but that'll be hard given your current code because you named the class and the instances the same thing. If you renamed the class to Box, the you could use `Box.on`.

Comment: well just to be clear I have save this as Box.lua as class                  Box = {}
m={}
m.random = math.random

function Box:new(x,y)
     Box.on=false
     local Box = display.newRect(0,0,100,100)
     
     return Box
end ------then in my main.lua I created instances like this            ---in main.lua                                                      require"Box.lua"                                              box1=Box:new(23,55)                                                    box2=Box:new(44,66)   ---is this what you mean?Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess I got after couple of testing:)